# Matrix transformation that always works?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Consider the matrix

$$A_2:= \begin{pmatrix} a & b_1 \\  b_2 & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

Let $\sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then

$$\sigma_2  A_2 \sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b_2 \\  -b_1 & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

I wonder if I have the matrix

$$A_3:= \begin{pmatrix} a & b_1 & 0 \\ b_2 & a & c_1 \\  0 & c_2 & a \end{pmatrix}$$
if there is an analogous matrix

$\sigma_3$ that works for all possible choices of coefficients in $A_3$ such that

$$\sigma_3 A_3 \sigma_3^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b_2 & 0 \\ -b_1 & a & -c_2 \\  0 & -c_1 & a \end{pmatrix}.$$

That there exists one such matrix for each set of coefficients is clear, since the eigenvalues of the two $3x3$ matrices are the same. I am looking for one that works for all choices.

Comment: Do you want $\sigma_3$ to be a unitary matrix?

Comment: @IosifPinelis actually invertible is fine, but yes, initially I had unitary in mind. Thanks a lot for clarifying this.

Comment: You have $\sigma_2 A_2 \sigma_2$ but $\sigma_3 A_3 \sigma_3^{-1}$.  Do you want $\sigma_3 A_3 \sigma_3$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Notice that $\sigma_2$ is self-involutive, i.e. $\sigma^2_2=1,$ which is why I am happy with the statement as written in the question.

Comment: $\sigma_3 A_3 \sigma_3^{-1}$ won't work: you can explicitly solve the linear system $\sigma_3 A_3 = B_3 \sigma_3$ where $B_3$ is your other $3 \times 3$ matrix and $\sigma_3$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix of variables, and see that all nontrivial solutions depend on $c_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, let $T:=\sigma_3=(t_{ij}\colon i,j\in\{1,2,3\})$, $A:=A_3$, and
$$B:=\begin{pmatrix} a & -b_2 & 0 \\ -b_1 & a & -c_2 \\  0 & -c_1 & a \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the equality in question would imply that
$$TA=BT \tag{1}
\label{1}$$
for all $a,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$. Solving system \eqref{1} of linear equations for the $t_{ij}$'s, we get
$$b_1 t_{11}+c_2 t_{13}+b_2 t_{22}=0,\quad 
c_1 t_{12}+b_2 t_{23}=0$$
for all $b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$.
It follows that
$$t_{11}=t_{13}=t_{22}=0,\quad 
t_{12}=t_{23}=0,$$
so that $t_{11}=t_{13}=t_{12}=0$ and hence $\det T=0$, which precludes the desired identity $TAT^{-1}=B$. $\quad\Box$

---

In fact, one can see that, if \eqref{1} holds for all $a,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$, then necessarily $T=0$.